# Cannot add another property to angular 5 request call

Tags: c#, angular, api, angular5

I asked a question a few days ago about my api service [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50781798/angular-5-cannot-find-a-differ-supporting-object-object-object-of-type-ob)

I had problems getting the right model back when my api call looked like this:

```
    //api call
return this.http.post<IListItem[]>(this.employmentListUrl, body, { headers: head })
    .do(data => JSON.stringify(data))
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

and with help from that question I got it to work like this:

```
        //api call 
    return this.http.post<{ EmploymentList: IListItem[] }>(this.employmentListUrl + "?skip="+skip+"&take="+take, body, { headers: head })
        .map(data => data.EmploymentList)
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

That "EmploymentList" is a property from a backend .net model called "ApiModel". It has two properties: "EmploymentList" and "TotalCount" (thats an int). FYI I return the whole ApiModel btw.

Now I would also like to have "TotalCount property. How to best do this? I tried:

```
    getFilteredEmploymentList(filterStr: string, orgNoParam: string, unitIdParam: string, skip: number, take: number): Observable<IListItem[]> {
    //... Params, headers, body... 

    //api call 
    return this.http.post<{ EmploymentList: IListItem[], TotalCount: number }>(this.employmentListUrl + "?skip="+skip+"&take="+take, body, { headers: head })
        .map(data => data.EmploymentList).map(data => data.TotalCount)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

but this gives me an error on "data.TotalCount" of: "Property "TotalCount" does not exist on "ListItem[]", I thought it was because of my Observable that is of type "ListItem[]". So I tried changing the Observable to "any" but I still get the same error.

EDIT: I solved this by creating an interface for the apimodel and used it in the api request like so:

```
export interface IEmploymentApiViewModel {
EmploymentList: IListItem[];
TotalCount: number; }
```

And the api call like so:

```
    getFilteredEmploymentList(filterStr: string, orgNoParam: string, unitIdParam: string, skip: number, take: number): Observable<IEmploymentApiViewModel> {
    //set headers, body... 
    .....

    let url = this.employmentListUrl + "?skip=" + skip + "&take=" + take;

    //api call 
    return this.http.post<IEmploymentApiViewModel>(url, body, { headers: head })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your API is returning an array of objects.
I usually have a model made for paging purpose with a property that contains total item count and another property with the array items. Eg (c#):

```
public class PageModel 
{
    public int TotalCount { get;set; }
    public List<MyModel> Items { get;set; }
}
```

And the same model in Angular to map it to.

Comment: Exactly, I got help from a collegue who did exactly this. Mapped the model to an interface he created. Ill post my changes and mark this as an answer anyways. Thank you!